# Set partition location in Qubole metastore using Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, qubole

How to set partition location for my Hive table in Qubole metastore?
I know that this is MySQL DB, but how to access to it and pass a SQL script with a fix using Spark?

UPD: The issue is that ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION (partition_spec)] SET LOCATION works slowly for >1000 partitions. Do you know how to update metastore directly for Qubole? I want to pass locations in a batch to metastore to increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

Set Hive metastore uris in your Spark config, if not set already. This can be done in the Qubole cluster settings.

Setup a SparkSession with some properties

```
val spark: SparkSession =
    SparkSession
        .builder()
        .enableHiveSupport()
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true")
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
        .getOrCreate()
```

Assuming AWS, define an external table on S3 using `spark.sql`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE foo (...) PARTITIONED BY (...) LOCATION 's3a://bucket/path'
```

Generate your dataframe according to that table schema.

Register a temp table for the dataframe. Let's call it `tempTable`

Run an insert command with your partitions, again using `spark.sql`

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE foo PARTITION(part1, part2)
SELECT x, y, z, part1, part2 from tempTable
```

Partitions must go last in the selection

Partition locations will be placed within the table location in S3.

If you wanted to use external partitions, check out the Hive documentation on `ALTER TABLE [PARTITION (spec)]` that accepts a `LOCATION` path

Comment: Jordan, this overwrites data. The issue is that ALTER TABLE table_name [PARTITION (partition_spec)] SET LOCATION works slowly for >1000 partitions. Do you know how to update metastore directly for Qubole? I want to pass locations in a batch to metastore to increase performance.

Comment: Remove the `OVERWRITE` if you don't want to wipe any data. I personally don't work with a metastore within Qubole. I have only worked with self-installed RDS databases, for example in AWS. it's just a cloud hosted instance somewhere... So, open a ODBC/JDBC port, then write the necessary INSERT statements to the Hive metastore. I don't know what database you're using, so the query will differ based on that.